# Flutter widget class with the same name share the same instance unexpectedly

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create 3 tab screens (say screenA, screenB and screenC) and each screen need to have their own navigator.

```
class TabNavigator extends StatefulWidget {
  final int tabID;
  TabNavigator({this.tabID});

  @override
  _TabNavigatorState createState() => _TabNavigatorState();
}

class _TabNavigatorState extends State<TabNavigator> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Navigator(
      initialRoute: "/",
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
        switch (settings.name) {
          case '/':
          default:
            if(widget.tabID == 1) {
              return CupertinoPageRoute(
                  builder: (_) => ScreenA(), settings: settings);
            }
            else if(widget.tabID == 2) {
              return CupertinoPageRoute(
                  builder: (_) => ScreenB(), settings: settings);
            }
            else {
              return CupertinoPageRoute(
                  builder: (_) => ScreenC(), settings: settings);
            }
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the code of my TabView. When the tabID is changed, the `print(widget.tabID);` can successfully print out the correct tabID.

```
class TabView extends StatefulWidget {

  final int tabID;

  TabView({
    this.tabID
  });

  @override
  _TabViewState createState() => _TabViewState();
}

class _TabViewState extends State<TabView> {

  Map<int, Widget> tabViews   = {
    1: new TabNavigator(tabID: 1),
    2: new TabNavigator(tabID: 2),
    3: new TabNavigator(tabID: 3)
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(widget.tabID);  
    switch(widget.tabID) {
      case 1:
      case 2:
      case 3:
        return tabViews[widget.tabID];
        break;
      default:
        return tabViews[1];
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

However, the problem is that `onGenerateRoute` in TabNavigator will be only called once (I expect it should be called 3 times). As a result, no matter how the tab (tabID) is changed, the initial route of the navigator is always directed to `ScreenA()`.

The only way I can make it works is to duplicate the `TabNavigator` to `TabNavigatorA`, `TabNavigatorB` and `TabNavigatorC` but I quite sure there should be some other ways to do it.

Comment: I find it hard to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: To be simple, I try to create 3 separate navigators but it seems like only 1 navigator is created (it seems like 3 navigator shares the same instance)

Comment: In your switch...case, shouldn't you put a break statement for each case?